# grep issue in Perl

Tags: regex, shell, perl

Below are from Perl script..

```
$search2=  join(' ', $mo,$day,$hr); # Output "Aug 2 03"
$LOG1  = "/tmp/log"  # Log file path. It has $search2 inside it
$search1 = "issue|error"
```

Here is the line where I am getting issue ...

```
$failed = `"/bin/egrep" "$search1" "$LOG1"| grep "$search2"`;
```

without `grep "search2"` getting below like output

```
Aug  1 01:03:40 something sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=something uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser= something=  user=something
Aug  1 03:34:20 something  sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=something uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser= something=  user=something
Aug  2 00:43:29 something sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=something uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser= something=  user=something
Aug  2 03:02:33 someting  sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=something uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser= something=  user=something
```

but when using `| grep "$search2"` not getting anything

```
   print "$failed"; # It is not throwing any output of 'Aug 2 03'
```

however when the same I am executing on Linux command line I am getting the required output . The below I am using on linux command line

```
/bin/egrep "issue|error" "/tmp/log" | grep  "Aug 2 03"
```

Please help to fix it .

Comment: Why are you using grep when Perl excels at such tasks itself? And are you sure that the command you're running from Perl is the same as what you're running on the command line?

Comment: Yes I am running same command in linux shell, one difference is  i am not using ` `  and not saving inside a variable...

Comment: I am quite new to perl , so really need help... to fix `$failed = `"/bin/egrep" "$search1" "$LOG1"| grep "$search2"`;` so that i can use $failed as output to send over email.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying? Show us the simplest thing that does not work.

Comment: `grep $search2` is not throwing any output inside the perl script , however in shell command its working . @ctrl-alt-delor Is it what you are asking for ?

Comment: No, I asked you to discover the simplest program that exhibits this error (I suspect one line + the print), and then to post it at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Seems I did not understand it exactly, however I have just added the content from log file if that can clear it..

Comment: There seem to be several spaces (or a tab?) between `Aug` and the number following it in your data, when your grep pattern only contains a single space. Could that be the issue?

Comment: No, space isnot an issue i believe as it will working on shell command.  I had tried print `"$search2"` and its showing output with space that I really want , so that the `grep` should work

Comment: Can you see the output of print qq="/bin/egrep" "$search1" "$LOG1"| grep "$search2"=;  i suspect $search2 is not what you think it is

Comment: @Dada I fixed `join` for space and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I think you should follow the advice given by Dada in his comment. If that what you posted is REALLY what you see, this can't work:

You build up your string like this:

```
$search2=  join(' ', $mo,$day,$hr);
```

This means that you have one space between month and day. Further, you copied the output which you get without using the search string, like this:

```
Aug  1 01:03:40 something sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=something uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser= something=  user=something
```

This clearly is NOT a single space between Aug and 1.

I am pretty sure that if you look at your file `/tmp/log` with a hex editor, you will NOT see a single space between "Aug" and "1".

You can also invoke the command from the command line and pipe it to, say, `xxd`, for seeing the hexadecimal content.

Comment: Let me recheck it.

Comment: @RishuA You should use `sprintf` for more control over the format. `$search2 = sprintf( '%s %2d %s', $mo, $day, $hr );`

Comment: Nice ! Got it .

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call out to grep for this:

```
use autodie;
open my $fh, "<", $LOG1;
my $failed = "";
while (<$fh>) {
    $failed .= $_ if /$search1/o && /$search2/o;
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: $search1 is a regex pattern, so `/$search1/` is fine, but `$search2` is text, so `/$search2/` should be `/\Q$search2/`. (That's why the OP was using `egrep` for the first and `grep` for the second.)

Comment: yes, or `index($_, $search2) != -1`. Your parenthetical remark is debatable.

Comment: Oh, why do you think they didn't use `grep` for both?

Comment: I suspect `egrep` just to avoid having to backslash the pipe. And to escape the backslash in perl within backticks.

Comment: And conversely, the other string should be matched literally. Which is what I said in the parenthetical

Comment: Yeah, but using grep for "text" matching is not quite accurate: still a regex. Just a quibble.

Comment: A string to match literally is NOT a regex pattern

Comment: i know all this. you claimed the OP was using grep to match literal text, which I found debatable. And here we are, debating it. I guess I win ;)

Comment: We covered this. They would have used `egrep` otherwise